# How to install dependencies of react-mgtEvents

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I am new to SharePoint Framework.
I would like to add the [react-mgtEvents](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-mgtEvents) sample web part to my SharePoint Online site.
I installed the node-js version from the below URL:

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.24.1/

After that, I tried to execute the npm install command on the react-mgtEvents folder path.

```
npm i @microsoft/mgt-react
```

However, I am getting the below errors after it finishes:
[image: npm error]
What are the dependencies that should be installed for this solution to make it run successfully and upload the app to the SharePoint app catalog?

In addition, I ran the npm outdated command and found the below:

[image: npm outdated]

Can please someone provide the steps/commands needed which should be executed?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that directory might be corrupted, can you try deleting your

- node_modules

then run:

- npm cache clean --force
- npm install
- npm i @microsoft/mgt-react

I tried in a new project, and had no issues myself:

```
//empty folder C:/testini
```

npm ini

npm i @microsoft/mgt-react

Comment: thank you for your reply. I tried to repeat the first two steps mentioned but the same issue occurs. Is there any library I am missing to install since I installed only the NodeJS? The SharePoint framework is not installed on my end, please find the updated error [here](https://imgur.com/tUswiLy). If it is required to be installed what is the command that should be executed? I look forward to your response.